# Doubt in Java interface implements

Tags: java

```
interface Device
{
  public void doIt();
}

public class Electronic implements Device
{
   public void doIt()
   {
   }
}

abstract class Phone1 extends Electronic
{
}
abstract class Phone2 extends Electronic
{
   public void doIt(int x)
   {
    }
}

class Phone3 extends Electronic implements Device
{   
    public void doStuff()
    {
     }
}
```

Can any one tell me why this compiles.. Because  "Phone3" implements Device and it should have doIt() method but it does not have. But still this compiles. May i know Y?

Comment: 14 questions and no accepted answers? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`implements Device` is redundant in class `Phone3` definition. The class in inheriting the fact of implementing the `Device` interface from the `Electronic` class.

That is, every class extending `Electronic` is implementing `Device` also, and is also inheriting the implementation of `doIt` that `Electronic` provides. Every one of them can  extend/provide a different implementation of `doIt` by overriding it.

Answer (score 6):

`Phone3` extends `Electronic`, and `Electronic` has the method `doIt()`, implementing the `Device` interface. The implementation of the `doIt` method is thus just inherited from the `Electronic` base class.

It makes sense if you make the example more realistic. Change `Device` to `Ringable`, with a `ring` method. Create a base class `SimplePhone` implementing `Ringable`, with an implementation of the `ring` method. And make a subclass of `SimplePhone` called `BeautifulPinkPhone`. The beautiful pink phone will be able to ring because it's just a simple phone with a pink color.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Phone3 extends Electronic and Electronic already implements doIt() method.

Answer (score 1):

it works, because `Electronic` implements `Device`. have you tried compiling without interface implementation in main class?

Comment: No..But i understood y it compiled Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`Phone3` inherits it from the `Electronic` class.

Answer (score 1):

Phone3 extends Electronic and inherits all it's methods.  Since Electronic has a doIt() method it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

`Phone3` extends `Electronic` hence it inherits `doIt()` method

Answer (score 1):

> If you see in a above code, Phone3 already implemented doIt() method
>   in a inheritance tree,i.e in a Electronic class, and if you wish to
>   call doIt() method in your Phone3 class it'll work fine such as.

```
class Phone3 extends Electronic implements Device
{   
public void doStuff()
{

}
public static void main(String...args)
{
    Phone3 p3=new Phone3();
    p3.doIt();
}
}
```

Comment: @sai sindhu, if remove the implements Device from your Electronic class, then it also work because the method that is present inside the Device interface, the same method you define in your Electronic clas

Answer (score 0):

`Phone3` extends `Electronic`, which already implements `doIt`.

Answer (score 0):

Cause Phone3 also extends Electronic which has a empty implementation for the doIt method.
So it does not need to have it, unless it needs to override the behaviour.